# How to recover from a failed merge in Git

Tags: git, merge

I am cooperating with a friend on a small project, and we use Git as source version control. This is the problem scenario:

1. I started working from version A, and had a few local commits to version B.
2. My friend also started from A, and pushed version C to the central repo.
3. I did 'git pull --rebase' and pushed version B. So the remote repo was like A->C->B.
4. At the meantime, my friend was still working on version C he pushed. When he tried to push version D, he did a failed merge (I don't know how he exactly did it). The result was that, the commit D contained changes from C->D, but discarded changes from A->B. So the remote repo looks like A->C->B->D at the moment, but the version D removed all changes from C->B

I am wondering what is the most easiest way to fix this failed merge.

Comment: You can use `git reflog` to find out where you were before you started the merge, then check out that hash and try again.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Everyone should read this post by Torvalds: http://lwn.net/Articles/328438/ -- don't synchronize your repositories just whenever, but only synchronize them at points that make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your friend could also possibly have done was a `git push --force`, resulting in `A-C-D`.

One way would be for you to `push --force` your content (`A-C-B`) again, and for your friend to:

- checkout a `tmp` branch on top of his current work
- `git fetch origin`
- reset his `master` branch to `origin/master`
- cherry-pick `D` from `tmp` branch back to master (a merge might be involved there)
- `git push origin`